# kubernetes: URLs for Mysql operator YAML stable versions

Tags: kubernetes, mysql-cluster, mysql8

Install mysql operator:

Following https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-operator/en/mysql-operator-installation-kubectl.html

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysql/mysql-operator/trunk/deploy/deploy-crds.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysql/mysql-operator/trunk/deploy/deploy-operator.yaml
```

They are from trunk. What are the URLs for latest stable versions?

tried:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mysql/mysql-operator/tags/8.0.33/deploy/deploy-crds.yaml

Not reachable.

should use the following from github?

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-operator/blob/8.0.33-2.0.10/deploy/deploy-crds.yaml